# When is it right to send an email when a conference misses its deadline?

Tags: conference

I have sent an article for a conference in Computer Science and in the Important Dates of the call for papers, it says the notification to the authors is April 20. Now we are at April 22 and the status of my paper still appears as Under Review. I was wondering how many days should I wait for sending a remainder email to see what has happened with my submission?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fairly frequent, particularly for smaller or less tightly run computer science conferences, for the response to authors to slip back by a few days.  Often, this is because some reviewers may not have sent their reviews in on time, and if the program committee isn't proactive about scheduling for slippage and having backups available, it may take them a few extra days to get enough reviews to decide on those papers.  This then is likely to delay responses for *all* of the papers, because both the organizers and the conference software wants to sent all of the notifications at once.

So, to your question of what to do:

1. If you know anybody else who sent in a paper, compare notes with them.  If they haven't heard yet either, no worries.  If they have heard, then you can email immediately.
2. If you don't know somebody else, give it a week, and then ask.

Answer (score 1):

As an abstract management system, we work with a lot of academic conferences. Quite often, the organisers don't even communicate the deadline for author notification officially.
Just like a high number of conferences will extend the submission deadline because authors submit at the last minute, more often than not, the peer review process will last a bit longer than anticipated because reviewers haven't completed their reviews yet. Besides, picking which submission to accept and which to reject might also take more time and push back the final decision.

I agree that waiting for a week before contacting anybody is reasonable. 
Then you can email the Chair or the programme chair to ask if they could give you an idea of when the results will be published.